# Error publishing NodeJS app to Azure

Tags: .net, iis, node.js, windows-7, azure

I installed the SDK with no problems and was following along with the Hello World example. When I get to the `Publish-AzureService` command it fails:

```
PS C:\code\node\tasklist\WebRole1> Publish-AzureService -name TaskListContoso -l
ocation "North Central US" -launch
Publish-AzureService : An error occurred creating the configuration section han
dler for system.serviceModel/commonBehaviors: Extension element 'Microsoft.Visu
alStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' cannot be added to this element
.  Verify that the extension is registered in the extension collection at syste
m.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
Parameter name: element (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\m
achine.config line 323)
At line:1 char:21
+ Publish-AzureService <<<<  -name TaskListContoso -location "North Central US"
 -launch
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureService], Configur
   ationErrorsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AzureDeploymentCmdlets.Cmdlet.PublishAzureServic
   eCommand
```

I've searched everywhere and have not been able to find a solution. I've done everything short of re-install windows but heading there soon.

Comment: Just a quick thought considering System.ServiceModel is a WCF namespace, do you have the WCF [Non-]Http Activation enabled? it's found in the Add/Remove Windows Features menu (available in Control Panel\Programs)

Comment: yeah both WCF Http Activation and Non-HTTP activation are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your machine.config.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior is a wcf behavior that enables wcf debugging features inside visual studio, and it loooks like something removed the behavior extension from your machine configuration without removing the references to it in common endpoint and service behaviors.

If the dll (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink) is installed on your computer (should be in the Global Assembly Cache if so, \windows\assembly), then you should be able to add the extension element back into your machine .config:

inside

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

If the dll isn't installed, you can remove the references to it in machine.config at:

```
system.serviceModel/commonBehaviors/endpointBehaviors
```

and

```
system.serviceModel/commonBehaviors/serviceBehaviors
```

Note that you will want to BACK UP your machine.config before making any changes.

Comment: here is what the behavior extension should look like:

Comment: edited out part of my my answer, the extension element for this behavior is in system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions:     '    <add name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>'

Comment: You guys are true heros! Not sure what the deal was but I commented out the whole <commonBehaviors /> section and that fixed it! Thanks!!!